# Random uniform point distribution on a square (with a catch)

Tags: algorithm, random, uniform

Ok, so the problem of uniform point distribution is solved by some well known algorithms (Hammersley, Monte Carlo etc.). However, my situation is a bit different: lets say I have the set **a** of values (2, 8, 1, 5, 4, 7, 3, 6). Those values are accessed sequentially by index (starting with 2). If they are mapped on the x axis (by access pattern, ie. at 0 is 2, at 1 is 8), I have to find their corresponding y value, such that:

- the whole point set (both x and y coords considered) are **not** a low-discrepancy sequence;
- any pair of x values (the input set) must have their corresponding y values with a maximum distance between them;

Result is another set **b** with mixed integers [1..8] as the first, so every tuple (ai, bi) follows the two rules above.

To summarize: I have the distribution over one axis (no matter which one) and need to find the distribution over the other, such that consecutive points, when accessed, are far away from each other but overall, forming an uniform distribution on the whole square.

**An example case**

Given the input set of 4 elements (3,1,4,2), a good result set is (xy merged): ((3,1),(1,4),(4,2),(2,3)) and it is good because when you access the points (from 3,1 until end), with every new point you access you make a big leaps on *both* axes, which is the goal along with overall equal distribution. A bad result case for same input set is: ((3,1),(1,2),(4,3),(2,4)), since now we access y values consecutively (although x values are ok).

This is all required to fill a precomputed table which will be used for sampling, so the speed of any eventual algorithm does not matter (as long as it does not take 2 years, of course). Any help appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I don't understand second condition. Please write one good and one bad solution to posted example and explain why they are good/bad.

Comment: @Dialecticus Ok, added an example. I hope it's clear now.

Comment: So in fact you are seeking a random-within-certain-criteria *permutation* of `[1..n]`, rather than a random point on a square? If `n` is small, compute the fitness of all `n!` permutations and uniformly pick one of the 'good enough' ones.

Comment: @AakashM Correct. I seek random sequence which adheres to both conditions above. Problem is, brute force wont work, because N (=> number of points) is 65536.

Comment: Ah! Yes, I don't think *anyone* has the time to compute a function on `65536!` inputs :)

Comment: I also should note that it is quite possible that a suitable algorithm (for a number this big) does not exist. But I'm not that good at mathematically analyzing problems, so I don't know.

Comment: So, we are searching for longest path of a multi-line, if x coordinates of all points are given as one permutation, and y coordinates are required to be another permutation?

Comment: @Dialecticus Correct. Complexity comes from trying to adhere to both conditions. So the points in this longest path must also form a point cloud with uniform distribution.

Comment: Is there a reason not to sample some 2000 random permutations and take one that produces the longest path?

Comment: I need a close to optimal solution for a set of 65536 elements, which cannot be permutated that many times. Even if it could, every single permutation needs to be checked if it is a part of uniform distribution set (combined with the constant permutation). Which is not trivial and takes time too.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use divide and conquer strategy to achieve this. Basically, if you want a permutation of 1:n, then create a permutation of 1:n/2 and (n/2+1):n, and intersperse them randomly.

Here is how you can intersperse them randomly:

```
function permute(x,y):
    L1 = permute(x, (x+y)/2)
    L2 = permute((x+y)/2+1, y)
    spin = randomlyselectfrom(-1,1)
    L = []
    while L1 and L2 are not empty:
        if spin<0:
            L.enqueue(L1.dequeue)
        else:
            L.enqueue(L2.dequeue)
        if random()<0.9:
            spin = -spin
    return L
```

I have left out checking for boundary conditions etc, feel free to ask me if you don't know how to take care of that part.

Once you get two random sequences in the above fashion, reverse one of those and pair them up, and you would get the pair sequence you need.